# How to derive this inequality from Peetre's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose we are given  the following inequality, which holds for any real number $s$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

\begin{equation}
(1 + |x + y|)^s \leq (1 + |x|)^s(1 + |y|)^{|s|} 
\end{equation}

(This is sometimes called Peetre's Inequality). How can I use this to show that, for a given integer $k$ and real number $d$, and $\xi,\eta \in \mathbb{R}^n$

\begin{equation}
(1 + |\xi|)^{d}(1 + |\xi - \eta|)^{-k}(1 + |\eta|)^{-k} \leq (1 + |\xi|)^{|d|-k}(1 + |\eta|)^{|d| - k}
\end{equation}

This is stated in some notes I am currently studying to learn about Fourier Analysis. I cannot fill in the details, I always end up with more terms than there ought to be .. any help would be great !!

Comment: The LHS is not symetric whereas the RHS is so; what happens if $\xi=\eta$ and $k>2|d|-d$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Hm .. Following your suggestion I deduce the inequality does not hold. I wonder what the author of my notes intended to write instead , have to work that out. 1000 thanks for your help !!

Comment: I guess we will apply it in an integration, so you will be able to deduce what he/she meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $(1+|\eta|)^{-k}$ is a common factor, we just have to show that 
$$(1+|\xi|)^d(1+|\xi-\eta|)^{-k}\leq (1+|\xi|)^{|d|-k}(1+|\eta|)^{|d|-k}.$$
We can write 
$$(1+|\xi|)^d(1+|\xi-\eta|)^{-k}=(1+|\xi-\eta+\eta|)^d(1+|\xi-\eta|)^{-k}$$
and since 
$$(1+|\xi-\eta+\eta|)^d\leq (1+|\xi-\eta|)^d(1+|\eta|)^{|d|}$$
we get 
$$(1+|\xi|)^d(1+|\xi-\eta|)^{-k}\leq (1+|\xi-\eta|)^d(1+|\eta|)^{|d|}(1+|\xi-\eta|)^{-k}$$
and finally
$$(1+|\xi|)^d(1+|\xi-\eta|)^{-k}\leq (1+|\xi-\eta|)^{|d|-k}(1+|\eta|)^{|d|}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I am not sure, maybe I miss the last step but what I need is the first factor of the right hand side to be $(1 + |\xi|)^{|d| - k}$ instead of  $(1 + |\xi - \eta|)^{|d| - k}$